# How to store value Permanently using sharedPreference after uninstalling the application

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, sharedpreferences

I am working on In-App Prurchase in Android. After Purchasing an item, i set boolean value to be true using Shared Preference Api in Android.It works fine. Once i un-install and re-install my application,it make boolean value to be false.This is my code:

```
boolean  buyUfo = false;
private static final String BUYUFO ="buyUfo";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);

    sharedPreference = this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCE_ID, MODE_PRIVATE);
    buyUfo = sharedPreference.getBoolean(BUYUFO, false);
     }

   //After In-App Purchase, when finish listener is called.
   IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener1 = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
                public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
                    Log.d("ufo", "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);
                   if (result.isFailure()) {
                        if (result.getResponse() == IabHelper.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
                            Editor editor = sharedPreference.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean(BUYUFO, true);
                            editor.commit();

                            return;
                        }
                     }
```

I want this value to be true always for those who bought the item?..Please help

Comment: shared preference is deleted on app uninstall but retained during update. You should save it in your server.

Comment: How do i save this specific boolean in the server?

Comment: just send it as a string true or false. And later query your server for the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it on the sdCard making a file for the same. But that can be deleted externally also.

For your concern, regarding:
***I want this value to be true always for those who bought the item?***
 with the In-App purchase, after purchasing an item, you don't really Need to store whether it has been purchased or not. The API would do it for you, through which you can fetch the status of an item for a particular id.

> To retrieve the list of product's owned by the user, your application
>   sends a getPurchases call to Google Play. Your application can make a
>   consumption request by sending a consumePurchase call. In the request
>   argument, you must specify the in-app product's unique purchaseToken
>   String that you obtained from Google Play when it was purchased.
>   Google Play returns a status code indicating if the consumption was
>   recorded successfully.

Read more on:
[Consuming In-app Products, In-app Billing V3](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume)

OR
[RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS in V2](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/api.html)

Comment: not right now, will revert if i find something. Last thing i remember, what you can also do is every time the app launches, in addition to the screen which involves the in-app purchase, check if the item is purchased asynchronously, on your splash or base class and set a sharedPref there - as true or false. Then you can utilize that value to trigger rest of the actions in your app everywhere

Answer (score 1):

See [Storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) android. I recommend saving sensitive data in your server(also google recommends it). In device you could save data in Shared Preference(not secure in rooted device is deleted on uninstall) or internal storage(deleted on uninstall) or external storage and sqlite databases. Whatever you choose if your data is sensitive then always encrypt it.

**Note** There is no reliable way to save data in device that persists between multiple installations. If you save it in external storage it is always prone to user deletion.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. If you tried implementing it that way, users would abuse your system by manually editing SharedPreferences.

User can clear his phone memory any time. You shouldn't rely on that. Instead, save value in your back end, and if user reinstalls app, check if it's the same user.

Comment: Actually this is the first time i implement In-App Purchase in an application.I follow one tuturial and it suggest me this way( using sharedpreference)..Do you know some other way?

Answer (score 0):

you have to store this value other than the sharedprefrences as,sharedprefrences are app specific and they are deleted when you uninstall and re-install the app.
What you can do is store this value on server and when the user installs the app again then you can retrieve the value and manipulate it according to its value

Comment: How do server return this value for specific user. Can you write solution interms of code?

Comment: you can do it according to the username,and if you do not have implemented any type of login for your user and use the google play or google+ username from which the purchase is happening

Comment: Actually this is the first time i implement In-App Purchase in an application.I follow one tuturial and it suggest me this way( using sharedpreference)..Do you know some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Saving the purchase information on `sharedPreference` is not the correct way. You should query the server to check if the user has purchased the item or not.